# State setted to initial value after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my situation: I have a component with some states. One of them (`documents`) is used to store the data of list of components, so the state is an array of objects.

A button make a request to the API which deletes one of this components on the system. After the request I want to remove from the state this element. I've implemented this (function `removeDocument`) with a filter that return an array that is used in `setDocuments` as an argument. Developing this I've noticed that the state `documents` was empty. **Why are this happening if I didn't call `setDocuments` anywhere?**

#### Component code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, View, Image, Text, InteractionManager, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styles from './style';
import mainStyles from '../../style';
import UserInfo from '../../../../config/context';
import { AcademicCapOutline, BanOutline, BriefcaseOutline, CalendarOutline, CashOutline, CheckCircleOutline, DocumentDuplicateOutline, EyeOutline, FingerPrintOutline, FlagOutline, HeartOutline, Home, HomeOutline, IdentificationOutline, InboxIn, InboxInOutline, LinkOutline, MailOutline, MapOutline, OfficeBuildingOutline, PencilAlt, PhoneIncomingOutline, PhoneOutline, Trash, ViewGridAdd } from 'react-native-heroicons';
import ButtonsRow from '../../../components/buttons/row/buttonsRow';
import ListTitle from '../../../components/listTitle/listTitle';
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import DocumentList from '../../../components/documents/documentList';
import DataList from '../../../components/list/dataList/dataList';
import { getUsers, getDocument, deleteDocument } from './api';
import Popup from '../../popup/popup';
import DocumentPopup from '../../popup/document/document';
import { useCallback } from "react";

const PersonScreen = (props) => {

  const { user, refreshToken } = useContext(UserInfo);
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([]);
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState({open: false});

  useEffect(() => {
    
    let b = [];

    if(user.rol != 'I' && user.rol != 'P'){

      if(user.rol == 'G')
        b.push({key: '3', icon: ViewGridAdd, action: () => console.log('hola')});

      if(user.rol == 'A')
        b = b.concat([
          {key: '1', icon: PencilAlt, action: () => console.log('hola')},
          {key: '2', icon: Home, action: () => console.log('hola')},
          {key: '3', icon: ViewGridAdd, action: () => console.log('hola')},
          {key: '4', icon: InboxIn, action: () => console.log('hola')},
          {key: '5', icon: Trash, action: () => console.log('hola')},
        ])

    }

    setButtons(b);

    var interaction = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions( () => {
    
      getUsers(user, refreshToken, props.id)
      .then(data => {

        setName(data.nombre);

        // Set Documents
        if(data.documentos){
          setDocuments(data.documentos.map( d => {
            return { ruta: d.ruta, title: d.documento.nombre, size: d.documento.tamano, type: 'Document', onPress: () => { openDocument( d.ruta, d.documento.nombre ) } }
          }))
        }

        // Set Data
        let d = [];

        if(data.activo != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'activo', icon: CheckCircleOutline, title:"Estado", data: ( data.activo ? 'Alta' : 'Baja' )})

        if(data.email)
          d.push({ key: 'email', icon: MailOutline, title:"Dirección de email", data: data.email})

        if(data.documento_id)
          d.push({ key: 'documento_id', icon: IdentificationOutline, title:"Documento de identificación", data:data.documento_id})

        if(data.tipo_documento_id)
          d.push({ key: 'tipo_documento_id', icon: IdentificationOutline, title:"Tipo de documento de identificación", data:data.tipo_documento_id})

        if(data.fecha_nacimiento)
          d.push({ key: 'fecha_nacimiento', icon: CalendarOutline, title:"Fecha de nacimiento", data:data.fecha_nacimiento})

        if(data.genero)
          d.push({ key: 'genero', icon: FingerPrintOutline, title:"Genero", data:data.genero})

        if(data.direccion)
          d.push({ key: 'direccion', icon: MapOutline, title:"Dirección", data:data.direccion})

        if(data.ciudad)
          d.push({ key: 'ciudad', icon: OfficeBuildingOutline, title:"Ciudad", data:data.ciudad})

        if(data.pais)
          d.push({ key: 'pais', icon: FlagOutline, title:"País", data:data.pais})        

        if(data.telefono)
          d.push({ key: 'telefono', icon: PhoneOutline, title:"Teléfono", data:data.telefono})

        if(data.pais_nacimiento)
          d.push({ key: 'pais_nacimiento', icon: FlagOutline, title:"País de nacimiento", data:data.pais_nacimiento})

        if(data.pais_procedencia)
          d.push({ key: 'pais_procedencia', icon: FlagOutline, title:"País de procedencia", data:data.pais_procedencia})
        
        if(data.estado_civil)
          d.push({ key: 'estado_civil', icon: LinkOutline, title:"Estado civil", data:data.estado_civil})

        if(data.formacion)
          d.push({ key: 'formacion', icon: AcademicCapOutline, title:"Formación", data:data.formacion})
        
        if(data.ocupacion)
          d.push({ key: 'ocupacion', icon: BriefcaseOutline, title:"Ocupación", data:data.ocupacion})

        if(data.permiso_trabajo != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'permiso_trabajo', icon: BanOutline, title:"Permiso de trabajo", data: ( data.ocupacion ? 'Sí' : 'No' )})
          
        if(data.estado_documentacion)
          d.push({ key: 'estado_documentacion', icon: BriefcaseOutline, title:"Estado de la documentación", data:data.estado_documentacion})

        if(data.estado_empadronamiento)
          d.push({ key: 'estado_empadronamiento', icon: DocumentDuplicateOutline, title:"Estado de empadronamiento", data:data.estado_empadronamiento})

        if(data.tarjeta_sanitaria)
          d.push({ key: 'tarjeta_sanitaria', icon: HeartOutline, title:"Estado de tarjeta sanitaria", data:data.tarjeta_sanitaria})

        if(data.observaciones)
          d.push({ key: 'observaciones', icon: EyeOutline, title:"Observaciones", data:data.observaciones})

        if(data.cuota)
          d.push({ key: 'cuota', icon: CashOutline, title:"Cuota", data: `${data.cuota} €`})

        if(data.newsletter != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'newsletter', icon: InboxInOutline, title:"Quiere newsletter", data: ( data.newsletter ? 'Sí' : 'No' )})

        if(data.disponibilidad_mananas != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'disponibilidad_mananas', icon: CalendarOutline, title:"Disponibilidad de mañanas", data: ( data.disponibilidad_mananas ? 'Sí' : 'No' )})

        if(data.disponibilidad_tardes != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'disponibilidad_tardes', icon: CalendarOutline, title:"Disponibilidad de tardes", data: ( data.disponibilidad_tardes ? 'Sí' : 'No' )})

        if(data.disponibilidad_fines_de_semana != undefined)
          d.push({ key: 'disponibilidad_fines_de_semana', icon: CalendarOutline, title:"Disponibilidad en fin de semana", data: ( data.disponibilidad_fines_de_semana ? 'Sí' : 'No' )})

        if(data.experiencia_previa)
          d.push({ key: 'experiencia_previa', icon: EyeOutline, title:"Experiencia previa", data:data.experiencia_previa})

        setData(d);

      })
      .catch( e => {
        // Error
      })
      
    })

    return InteractionManager.clearInteractionHandle(interaction);
  }, [])

  const openDocument = (ruta, nombre) => {
    setPopup({
      open: true,
      component: DocumentPopup,
      title: nombre,
      componentProps: {
        remove: () => { removeDocument(ruta) },
        download: () => { downloadDocument(ruta) }
      }
    })
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setPopup({open: false});
  }

  const removeDocument = (ruta) => {
    deleteDocument(user, refreshToken, ruta)
    .then( removed => {
      console.log(documents) // <--- Array []

      if( removed ){
        setDocuments(documents.filter( d => { return d.ruta !== ruta } ));
      }
      
      closePopup();
    })
    .catch( e => {
      // Error
      console.log(e);
    } )
  }

  const downloadDocument = (ruta) => {
    getDocument(user, refreshToken, ruta);
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={[mainStyles.screenContainer, styles.mainView]}
      >
      <View style={styles.topSection}>
        <View style={styles.topInfo}>
          <Image 
            style={styles.image}
            source={require('../../../assets/default-person.png')}  
          />
          <View style={styles.nameView}>
            <Text 
              style={styles.name}
              numberOfLines={2}
              ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
            >{name}</Text>
            <View style={styles.location}>
              <HomeOutline 
                style={styles.homeIcon}
                stroke={'#121212'}
              />
              <Text style={styles.homeText}>Casa E | Habitación 3</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ButtonsRow
          buttons={buttons}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomSection}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          { documents.length!=0 && 
            <ListTitle title={'Documentos'} />
          }
          { documents.length!=0 && 
            <DocumentList
              style={styles.documents}
              documents={documents}
            />
          }
          { data.length!=0 && 
            <View style={styles.datos}>
              <ListTitle title={'Datos'} />
              <DataList data={data} /> 
            </View>
          }
          { documents.length==0 && data.length==0 && 
            <ActivityIndicator style={styles.loading} size="large" color="#054956" />
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
        { popup.open && <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} style={mainStyles.outsidePopup} onPress={closePopup} /> }
        { popup.open && 
          <Popup
            title={popup.title}
            component={popup.component}
            componentProps={popup.componentProps}
          />
        }
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );  

}

module.exports = PersonScreen;
```

Comment: is it happening because your component might be rerendering and setting the data as an empty array? I am new to react but can you try passing the document inside the array in useEffect hook. So that it re renders only when document is changed.

Comment: @AkshayBhat The state initial value is set as an empty array. Then when the animation that loads the component is finished, it get the data from the API and load it into the states. At this point, `documents` is an array with objects and the components are rendered properly. After that, `documents` is never changed until the user decided to remove one. At this point `documents` is an empty array (but the component is still showing them), I don't know why. In this process I've never use `setDocuments`.

Comment: i found this on the react docs might be helpful.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#:~:text=Passing%20an%20update%20function%20allows,state%60%20instead%20of%20%60this.

Passing an update function allows you to access the current state value inside the updater. Since setState calls are batched, this lets you chain updates and ensure they build on top of each other instead of conflicting:

Comment: Thank for the docs. I've already solve the issue with refs. I think I understand what are you saying, but my problem wasn't with setState. My problem doesn't come with the async behavior of setState because the elements render before the problem. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this solution:

I don't fully understand how React works at this situation but I found a solution using refs. I don't know why, but without modifying the state, it don't be always the latest one. To make sure that the one that I use is the last one, I've created a ref that points to the last version of `document` state:

```js
  {...}

  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState({open: false});
  const docsRef = useRef();

  docsRef.current = documents;
```

Now instead of using documents inside the functions, I use `docsRef.current`.